# Show the description instead the index on Microsoft bot FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework

I have an `enum` that have two options. When I show those options on the form they appear as their description/name but when the user select an option from the form box the selected option is displayed as numeric value instead as the description. For instance when user select Female the bot shows 1. I want the bot display: Female.

How can I display a description on an option selection?

Code fragment:

```
[Serializable]
public class Form
{

    public Gender Gender;
    ......
}

public enum Gender
{
  [Describe("Female"), Terms("Female")]
  Female=1,
  [Describe("Male"), Terms("Male")]
  Male
}
```

Show the description instead the index on Microsoft bot FormFlow

Comment: Does this happen in all channels or just the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and it's working perfectly for me in the latest emulator ([v3.5.25](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v3.5.25)) and with the latest release of BotBuilder ([v3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/releases/tag/Nuget3.5)). So, make sure to at least update the BotBuilder package.

Something that I notice though and that was making the sample to not work (not with the index thing but instead with no recognizing the value sent) is that the your both options in the enum, has the same term ("Female"). Make sure to update the second one to "Male"

Comment: What solved the issue? Updating to the latest builder?